# Can't change cursor and bubble color for Material TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

I want to change Material TextInputEditText's bubble and cursor color. I tried colorAccent, android:textCursorDrawable these are not working correctly.

[Files in here](https://0bin.net/paste/YUG05fSeo9gVCP49#ktXWEwmdAH0qDe1hTBr86wpgHUrr51ywhouqPOMSmcj)

[image: You can see it in this image]

Comment: Change your accent color in colors.xml

Comment: Pratik Butani I said it above, it doesn't work

Comment: Put your`xml` file with `style.xml`

Comment: [This link contains files](https://0bin.net/paste/YUG05fSeo9gVCP49#ktXWEwmdAH0qDe1hTBr86wpgHUrr51ywhouqPOMSmcj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use following attributes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">#2962FF</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#0039CB</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorError">#F44336</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#212121</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">#212121</item>
</style>

<color name="background">#FAFAFA</color>
```

To know more about : [Setting up a Material Components theme for Android](https://medium.com/over-engineering/setting-up-a-material-components-theme-for-android-fbf7774da739)

Comment: It's just about colorPrimary. When i changed colorPrimary and colorSecondary's color as blue, it solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20):

The material attribute color **colorControlActivated** do the magic. You have to create a style for your TextInputLayout.

e.g:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Then you have to apply this style in the theme attribute of control:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lblObservaciones"
                android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/blue"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/blue">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/comments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLength="200" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! The combination of a theme AND a style is what did it for me. So that I could have the combination I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Just apply **colorControlActivated** in app theme(day/night) and all Material TextInputEditField will have the changed cursor color

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
```