# Problem with bubble color of TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputedittext

i have a problem with an TextInputEditText, i want to change the color of bubble.
[TextInputEditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUWI3.jpg)
Xml layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MyTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewLogin">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My style:

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

here i've tried to add

```
 <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
```

but none of these worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487356/cant-change-cursor-and-bubble-color-for-material-textinputedittext

Comment: i've tried but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sample

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ..
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance" // add this line
    ..
   >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       ...
         android:id="@+id/email"
       ..
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170421/what-is-difference-among-styles-xml-and-themes-xml) for difference between **style** and **theme**